# Contact form PHP shows blank

Tags: php, html, forms, url

I took a standard form that I always use which included a comments are. For this website I don't need comments so I only left email and url in it. When I remove the everything related to comments in my PHP file it shows a blank page, not even an error.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "email@email.com";

    $email_subject = "NEW CONTACT";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['url'])) || {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $url = $_POST['url']; // not required


    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }


  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }


    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "url: ".clean_string($url)."\n";



// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Success

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra `||` in your if condition. Remove that and it should work.

```
if(!isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['url'])) || {
                          ^^^^
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}
```